# Past tense when noun clause is in the middle of the sentence

Tags: english-to-japanese, tense

For this sentence, how does past tense apply with noun clauses

> Mr Suzuki was writer who wanted to live near the forest

Do I say

> 鈴木さんは森林の近くに住みたい作家でした。

or

> 鈴木さんは森林の近くに住みたかった作家でした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would parse it: focus on the tense of the modifying clause.

> 森林の近くに住みた**い**。 (present state)
>
> > Mr. Suzuki **wants** to live near the forest.

> 森林の近くに住みた**かった**。(past state)
>
> > Mr. Suzuki **wanted** to live near the forest.

Hence, we have the following:

> A) 鈴木さんは森林の近くに住みたい作家でした。
>
> > a) Mr. Suzuki was a writer who **wanted** to live near the forest.

> B) 鈴木さんは森林の近くに住みたかった作家でした。
>
> > b) Mr. Suzuki was a writer who **had wanted** to live near the forest.

However, if the order of events is clear from the context, we can reduce *had wanted* to *wanted* in the translation. That is, **a** may be equal to **b** in meaning, but not in this case. In other words, we could translate **B** using **a** although it offers less information if no context is provided.